Variance of rounded standard normal random variable
I would like to evaluate the variance of $y=\mathrm{round}\,x$, where $x\sim\mathsf{Normal}(0,1)$. Using numerical integration, $\mathrm{var}\,y\approx 1.0833333223611180232$ which is very close to $13/12=1.08\bar{3}$. The numeric approximation is sufficient in practice, but I'm intrigued whether there's a closed form expression.

That would certainly be a remarkable result, if it is not a coincidence.

We certainly get the variance is: $$\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}n^2e^{-n^2/2}\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} e^{-x^2/2-xn},dx$$ But I definitely don't see any way to simplify that.

It probably is one of those odd coincidences given that the expressions do differ. It just took me by surprise that the difference would be $\sim10^{-8}$.

Even if it isn't exactly $1/12,$ there might be a reason it is close to $1/12$ - there might be a formula that gives $\frac1{12}-\epsilon,$ where $\epsilon$ is easily seen as small.

We have $$\sigma_Y^2 = 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2 \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{2 n+1}{2
   \sqrt{2}}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{2 n-1}{2
   \sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$$
Since the integral is known (have a look at the edit), we can use Euler-MacLauring summation formula which gives as a result
$$\sigma_Y^2 =\frac{13}{24} \left(\text{erfc}\left(\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}}\right)+\text{erfc}\left(\frac{3}{2 \sqrt{2}}\right)\right)+\frac{A e-B}{e^{9/8}\, \sqrt{2 \pi }\,\, C}$$
For the level of expansion I used
$$A=391959519200349098623471015$$
$$B=295705679483708634227815287$$
$$C=147325023391266593832960000$$
All of that gives $\sigma_Y^2=1.0833331$.
Edit
$$I=\int n^2\,\, \text{erf}\left(\frac{2 n+a}{2 \sqrt{2}}\right)\,dn$$ A few integration by parts give
$$I=\frac{1}{24} \left(8n^3+a^3+12 a\right)\text{erf}\left(\frac{2 n+a}{2 \sqrt{2}}\right)+\frac{4n^2-2 a n+a^2+8}{6 \sqrt{2 \pi }\,\exp\left(\frac{1}{8} (2 n+a)^2 \right) }
   $$

We will use the notation $$Y = \lfloor X + 1/2 \rfloor$$ to denote the nearest integer to $X$.  Then since $Y$ remains symmetric except on a set of measure $0$, we have $\operatorname{E}[Y] = 0$ and $$\sigma_Y^2 = \operatorname{Var}[Y] = \operatorname{E}[Y^2] = \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty \left \lfloor x + \frac{1}{2} \right \rfloor^2 \phi(x) \, dx$$ where $\phi$ is the standard normal density.  This in turn is expressible as an infinite sum:
$$\sigma_Y^2 = \sum_{y=-\infty}^\infty y^2 \int_{x=-1/2}^{1/2} f_X(y + x) \, dx = \sum_{y=-\infty}^\infty y^2 \left( \Phi(y+1/2) - \Phi(y-1/2) \right)$$
where $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal.  Again, the symmetry of $Y$ allows us to simplify this to
$$\sigma_Y^2 = 2 \sum_{y=1}^\infty y^2 \left( \Phi(y + 1/2) - \Phi(y - 1/2) \right).$$  At this point we can see it is unlikely that the sum has an elementary closed form expression.

Thank you. I had a look at similar expressions using error functions but couldn't make any further progress based on their properties.

"At this point, we can see...." Well, no, we can't see.  It is just supposition based on how ugly it looks.

@ThomasAndrews That's why I say unlikely.  Not "definitely."  You're more than welcome to prove me wrong.  Please, be my guest.
